# Install Shield-adding code

Tags: installshield

I am a beginner level user of InstallShield. I've added a button in the Wizard interface. Now I want to add some code that's to be executed  on clicking that. I don't Know the procedure to do that. Any Idea??

Comment: What project type are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read thexe blog articles to learn how to write and call DLL's from a suite installer.

[Calling a Function in a DLL from a Wizard Page or Window in a Suite Installation](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2011/12/calling-a-function-in-a-dll-from-a-wizard-page-or-window-in-a-suite-installation.html)

[Validating User Input in a Suite Project](http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/suite-installations/)